# Usb flash drive not detected

Tags: hard-drive, usb, bios

I have a problem wich is my usb flash drives are 8gb and 16gb not detected by ubuntu 21.04 but my hard drive 1tb is being detected.
I have disabled secure boot, fast boot and enabled csm and pxe on bios, but still nothing is changed. One thing which may be causing the issue is on bios the option of launch efi file system, which whenn i click on it shows ‘not found’, but i am not sure.
Also i have done lsub, lsblk,and some other commands to display it. I dont know what to do know, any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu supports UEFI mode, why did you enable CSM, legacy boot is outdated. Why are you enabling then attempting to launch UEFI boot, the two actions, are mutually exclusive to one another

Comment: The title of your posting is misleading as your posting is describing a boot problem whereas your title describes a hardware recognition problem. You might loose possible answers this way. Generally when I read inconsistent descriptions I stay away from answering because I fear endless dialogues in the comment sections to pull the necessary information out of the contributor...